# org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [boolean] for value 'N';

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Strange behaviour i am observing while fetching the Document from MongoDb using  Query and Criteria i am getting the error org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [boolean] for value 'N'

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(
                Criteria.where("salesDate").lt(new Date()).and("productStatus.isOfflineProduct")
                        .is(YesNoType.N.name()).and("productStatus.isVisibleProduct").is(YesNoType.N.name()));

        List<Product> products = mongoTemplate.query(Product.class).matching(query).all();
```

Enum type

```
public enum YesNoType {
    Y, N
}
```

ProductStatus.java

```
@Data
public class ProductStatus {

    private boolean isBestSellingProduct;
    private YesNoType isOfflineProduct;
    private YesNoType isVisibleProduct;

}
```

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {

@Id
private String id;
private ProductStatus productStatus;

}
```

Could anyone point out whats wrong with my query and with the class ProductStatus.java since after removing the isBestSellingProduct boolean field this code works fine.

Comment: Apparently the document doesn't contain a boolean but a `Y` or `N` like the other fields. Which cannot be converted to a boolean only `true`/`false`. SO it probably needs to be the enum type `YesNoType` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the help! you pointed out correctly. My document doesn't contain a boolean but a Y or N so after changing the isBestSellingProduct  to false or changing isBestSellingProduct type to YesNoType error is gone and working like a charm.